# Apache tutorial mentions Git version 3.5 but the most recent version is 2.10

Tags: git, apache

I wanted to work through [this Apache tutorial](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/prerequisites/prerequisites.html). Beneath prerequisites they list the needed software-versions:

> We assume you are familiar with Maven and Git and have installed at
>   least the following versions:
>
> - Maven Version 3.2.0
> - Git Version 3.5.1
> - JDK Version 1.6
>
> The tutorials are tested and work with this versions.

The problem is that the most [recent Git version is 2.10](https://git-scm.com) as this question is written. What do they mean?

Comment: So there is an error in that tutorial. But why do you ask _us_ about that?

Comment: The tutorial appears to have a typo, we should all downvote it.  Now the question is _which_ actual Git version does it expect you to use?  Well Git usually doesn't take away features as time goes on, so `2.10` should be fine.

Comment: Hm, would guess 2.5.1? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I do not think there's a typo in the version number. Instead I'm pretty sure they actually meant to refer to [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) version 3.5.1. This makes sense given that it's a standard Java/Eclipse stack tutorial.

Comment: @DUman: wouldn't that still count as a typo, in that it should say "EGit"? (I don't know if EGit is commonly called Git, so this is an actual question, but I hope the answer is "yes it counts as a typo" because calling two different things "Git" is a recipe for confusion...)

Comment: @torek Yes, what I meant was that it's not a typo in the version number itself, as in, 3.5.1 is correct. A bit of awkward phrasing, as EGit and Git are indeed not the same thing.